# I get the error "Output Limit Exceeded" on this below code

Tags: c++, error-handling

here's the code i made for finding jumping numbers less than or equal to a given no. it shows error "Output Limit Exceeded"

```
int main() {
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--)
{
    long long int n ,rem,temp;
    cin>>n ;
    for(int i=0 ; i<=n ; ++i)
    {
        if(i<=10)
        cout<<i<<" ";
        else
        {   
            temp=i;
           do                   
            {
               rem=i%10;
               i/=10;
            }while(abs(rem-i%10)==1);
            if(i==0)
            {
                cout<<temp<<" "; // printing jumping no.s
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Are you sure you want to modify your index 'i' inside your for loop?

Comment: what kind of machine are you running this on?

Answer (score 1):

You're dividing i by 10 in your do-while loop! As soon as i hits 11, it will be divided by 10, and then at the next iteration of the main for loop, you'll have a very low i value, back to where it was earlier. You're loop will never end.